# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, server, frontend

I am getting this error when I try to run ng serve:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown browser query

basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's

Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
See "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-wKwcJB\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3938

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: In the root of your application do you have a file called browserslist?

Comment: @MarnixHarderwijk yes there are: browserlist and browserlist.cmd I deleted them but I got a new error: 
ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #!/bin/sh
| basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

Comment: @Dortimer [error] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (D:\html_css\web-projects\Angular\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:204:10)
    at D:\html_css\web-projects\Angular\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:296:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (D:\html_css\web-projects\Angular\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:237:18)
    at browserslist (D:\html_css\web-projects\Angular\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:361:16)